# Prove that $\prod _{k=1}^n(1- \frac ak)$ diverges if $a>0$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Prove that $\prod _{k=1}^n(1- \frac ak)$ diverges if $a>0$ and $\prod _{k=1}^n(1+ \frac ak)$ diverges if $a>0$ as $n \to \infty$.
Taking logarithm both side we get $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \log(1- \frac ak)$ it is decreasing as $\log$ is an increasing function so $\prod _{k=1}^n(1- \frac ak)$ is decreasing and second one is increasing for the same reason. Now $0<1- \frac ak <1$ so $\log(x) < x-1$ hence $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \log(1- \frac ak)<-\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac ak$ hence divergent and for $\prod _{k=1}^n(1+ \frac ak)>1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac ak$ hence divergent. Now please check whether I have made any wrong statement or not.

Comment: May I know why I am down voted?

Comment: I didn't downvote you but I suppose that you got downvoted because you didn't show the thoughts you have about the problem.

Comment: Actually I find no clue how to proceed. Still thinking..

Comment: @user152715 People like to see that you've put some effort into trying to find your own solution, i.e. show your work. It makes it easier to offer useful, constructive help, and it helps avoid making people feel like they are just being used to do your homework for you (though that may not actually be the case).

Comment: Think about what happens to $\ln(1 + u)$ when $u \to 0$. (What does it behave like?)

Comment: It might be useful to try to prove some more general results. For example if $a_k$ is any sequence of positive numbers then we always have $\prod_{k=1}^n\left(1+a_k\right) \geq 1 + \sum_{k=1}^n a_k$. This can be 'seen' by imagining multiplying out the left hand side and can be proven using induction on $n$.

Comment: I have edited it to a solution. Please check if there is any error.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.**

Take the logarithm (it is defined for $k$ large enough) and compare it with the harmonic series.

Answer (score 0):

Hint. The first sequence is monotone decreasing and have upper bound equals to 1. The second is monotone increasing and has no upper bound. So the first converge and second diverge.

Comment: Will you give me clear proof? What do you mean by monotonically decreasing and have upper bounds? What will be the effect then?

Comment: Every monotone bounded sequence have a limit. Is the case for the first sequence. Monotone means $a_{n+1}\leq a_{n}$(decreasing) and $a_{n+1}\geq a_n$(increasing).

Comment: I know that but for a monotone decreasing sequence having an upper bound doesn't imply it is convergent think about it..

Comment: This sequence is clearly lower bounded, given $a$ take $n_0$ such that for every $k>n_0$ you have $a/k<1$. So the sequence is lower bounded, too. Therefore, bounded and monotone.

Answer (score 0):

For $\prod _{k=1}^n(1+ \frac ak)$,
more holds:

If $a_k \ge 0$,
then
$\prod_{k=1}^n(1+ a_k)
\ge 1+\sum_{k=1}^n a_k
$.

The proof is by induction.

It is true for $n=1$.

If it is true for $n$,
then

$\begin{array}\\
\prod_{k=1}^{n+1}(1+ a_k)
&=(1+a_{n+1})\prod_{k=1}^{n}(1+ a_k)\\
&\ge(1+a_{n+1})(1+\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k)\\
&=1+a_{n+1}+\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k+(a_{n+1}\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k)\\
&\ge 1+\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} a_k\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore,
if $a_k = \frac{a}{k}$,
$\prod_{k=1}^{n}(1+ \frac{a}{k})
\ge 1+\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{a}{k}
\to \infty
$
as
$n \to \infty$.

To go with subtraction
instead of addition,
this holds:
If $1 > a_k \ge 0$,
then
$\frac1{\prod_{k=1}^n (1-a_k)}
\ge \prod_{k=1}^n (1+a_k)
\ge 1+ \sum_{k=1}^n a_k
$.

This follows immediately from
$\frac1{1-a}
\ge 1+a
$
for
$0 \le a < 1$.

Therefore.
if $0 < a < 1$,
$\frac1{\prod_{k=1}^n (1-\frac{a}{k})}
\ge \prod_{k=1}^{n}(1+ \frac{a}{k})
\ge 1+\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{a}{k}
$.
Since
$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{a}{k}
\to \infty
$,
$\prod_{k=1}^n (1-\frac{a}{k})
\to 0
$.

Comment: Then when $\prod_{k=1}^n (1- \frac ak)$ diverges?

Comment: If I have to prove when does this product $\prod_{k=1}^n (1- \frac ak)$ diverges. What will be the statement and the proof?

Comment: The product diverges to zero when 0 < a < 1.

Comment: But you have proven in the proof that the product will converge to $0$.

Comment: I am saying when does this product diverges to $\infty$? Give me the condition and the proof..

Comment: It never diverges to $\infty$ - once $k > |a|$, the terms in the product are between 0 and 1, so the value does to zero.